# Convolutional1D in Keras convolves on time steps instead of features?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, lstm

So, my input is of shape `(1, 893, 463)`, or, more generally, `(None, None, 463)`. This corresponds to 1 sample of 893 time steps, each with 463 features. The output shape is `(1, 893, 2)`, i.e. `(None, None, 2)`.

My network structure looks like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution1D(64, 5, input_dim = one_input_length, border_mode = "same", W_regularizer = l2(0.01)))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(10, border_mode = "same"))
model.add(Convolution1D(64, 5, border_mode = "same", W_regularizer = l2(0.01)))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(10, border_mode = "same"))
model.add(GRU(300, return_sequences = True, W_regularizer = l2(0.01), U_regularizer = l2(0.01)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid')))
```

Compiled like this:

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Problem is, when I do `model.fit(test_X, test_Y, nb_epochs = ....)`, I get the following error: `Incompatible shapes: [1,893] vs. [1,9]`, tracing back to the `compile` line.

I logged the shapes of the outputs of each of the layers using [this](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-the-output-of-an-intermediate-layer) technique, coming up with this:

```
Input:  (1, 893, 463)
Conv_1: (1, 893, 64)
Pool_1: (1, 90, 64)
Conv_2: (1, 90, 64)
Pool_2: (1, 9, 64)
GRU:    (1, 9, 300)
Dense:  (1, 9, 2)
```

I suspect this occurs when the model tries to calculate accuracy, and finds that for 893 correct outputs, it only has 9 predictions. For some reason, the second `Convolutional1D` layer starts convolving on the time steps, not on the features, as the first one did.

Why is this, and how do I fix this?

## EDIT:

Model summary:

```
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                     Output Shape          Param #     Connected to
====================================================================================================
convolution1d_1 (Convolution1D)  (None, None, 64)      148224      convolution1d_input_1[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
maxpooling1d_1 (MaxPooling1D)    (None, None, 64)      0           convolution1d_1[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
convolution1d_2 (Convolution1D)  (None, None, 64)      20544       maxpooling1d_1[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
maxpooling1d_2 (MaxPooling1D)    (None, None, 64)      0           convolution1d_2[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
gru_1 (GRU)                      (None, None, 300)     328500      maxpooling1d_2[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
timedistributed_1 (TimeDistribut (None, None, 2)       602         gru_1[0][0]
====================================================================================================
Total params: 497,870
Trainable params: 497,870
Non-trainable params: 0
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

I am trying to make a CNN-LSTM classifier which, given time series data, will give an output for each time step.

Full error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/.pyenvs/MLPy3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1021, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/Users/user/.pyenvs/MLPy3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1003, in _run_fn
    status, run_metadata)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "/Users/user/.pyenvs/MLPy3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 469, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [1,893] vs. [1,9]
     [[Node: Equal = Equal[T=DT_INT64, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](ArgMax, ArgMax_1)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Stock_CNN_LSTM.py", line 89, in <module>
    model.fit(test_X, test_Y, nb_epoch=nb_epoch, verbose = 2, callbacks=[TestCallback((test_X, test_Y)), ModelCheckpoint("cnn_lstm_model-{epoch:02d}.h5")], initial_epoch = initial_epoch)
  File "/Users/user/.pyenvs/MLPy3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 672, in fit
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "/Users/user/.pyenvs/MLPy3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1192, in fit
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "/Users/user/.pyenvs/MLPy3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 892, in _fit_loop
    outs = f(ins_batch)
  File "/Users/user/.pyenvs/MLPy3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 1900, in __call__
    feed_dict=feed_dict)
  File "/Users/user/.pyenvs/MLPy3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 766, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/Users/user/.pyenvs/MLPy3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 964, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/Users/user/.pyenvs/MLPy3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1014, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/Users/user/.pyenvs/MLPy3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1034, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [1,893] vs. [1,9]
     [[Node: Equal = Equal[T=DT_INT64, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](ArgMax, ArgMax_1)]]

Caused by op 'Equal', defined at:
  File "Stock_CNN_LSTM.py", line 71, in <module>
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
  File "/Users/user/.pyenvs/MLPy3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 594, in compile
    **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/.pyenvs/MLPy3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 713, in compile
    append_metric(i, 'acc', acc_fn(y_true, y_pred))
  File "/Users/user/.pyenvs/MLPy3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/metrics.py", line 11, in categorical_accuracy
    K.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1)))
  File "/Users/user/.pyenvs/MLPy3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 1275, in equal
    return tf.equal(x, y)
  File "/Users/user/.pyenvs/MLPy3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 728, in equal
    result = _op_def_lib.apply_op("Equal", x=x, y=y, name=name)
  File "/Users/user/.pyenvs/MLPy3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 759, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/Users/user/.pyenvs/MLPy3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2240, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/Users/user/.pyenvs/MLPy3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1128, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Incompatible shapes: [1,893] vs. [1,9]
     [[Node: Equal = Equal[T=DT_INT64, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](ArgMax, ArgMax_1)]]
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you provide more info about what you are trying to achieve? why is your `TimeDistributed` is the last output? what is your target y dimensions?

Comment: Could you provide - the shapes of your input and output, print model.summary() and full error message?

Comment: Done. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now all the convolution/pooling layers are acting over time. If you want to apply them in the features space you would need to make them `TimeDistributed` and add an extra dimension at the end of your input. Then you would need to remove the extra dimension before passing the data to the `GRU` layer. However, you would only be able to do that if you have one channel output per convolution:

```
import keras.backend as K

model = Sequential()
model.add(Lambda(lambda x: K.expand_dims(x, -1)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Convolution1D(1, 5, input_dim = one_input_length, border_mode = "same", W_regularizer = l2(0.01))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling1D(10, border_mode = "same")))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Convolution1D(1, 5, border_mode = "same", W_regularizer = l2(0.01))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling1D(10, border_mode = "same")))
model.add(Lambda(lambda x: K.squeeze(x, -1)))
model.add(GRU(300, return_sequences = True, W_regularizer = l2(0.01), U_regularizer = l2(0.01)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid')))
```

If you want to use multiple output channel in your convolution then you would need to create some kind of "matrix" of GRU units.

Comment: That works, thank you. But why do I have to add another dimension for Convolutional and Pooling?

Comment: @IvanVegner Well I didn't check whether it works without it, but in principle 1D convolution works, for each example (with `TimeDistributed`, for each time step), with two dimensions, which are the convoluted dimension (the 463 features in your case) and the number of convoluted channels (in your case 1 number per features), so you add one dimension at the end so the convolution operation sees each number as a one-dimensional vector. I'm not sure if that helps, I know it's confusing :S

Comment: I... think I get it. It's necessary because each feature could have several "channels", and so to signify that it only has one, we have to add that dimension. Correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly :) So for example with images is typically 3 but in this case just 1.